# Number of 6-digit passwords, starting with even or ending with odd digit

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My problem is

> A password consists of six digits, each in $\{0,\ldots,9\}$
>   How many passwords start with an even digit or end with an odd digit?

the answer is $750,000.$

I would like to know how exactly do you get $750,000$ as the answer?

Comment: Hint: How many passwords do neither?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your set of passwords can be decomposed into three disjoint sets:

1) $2k,*, *, *, *, 2l$

2) $2k,*, *, *, *, 2l+1$

3) $2k+1,*, *, *, *, 2l+1$

In each one of these sets, there are
$$
5\cdot10^4\cdot5
$$
passwords.

Answer (score 8):

First count the number of combinations that start and end with even digits. Using the fundamental theorem of combinatorics we know this is $5\times10\times10\times10\times10\times5$.

Now count the numbers which start with an odd digit and ends with an even digit. This is $5\times10\times10\times10\times10\times5$.

And finally the numbers that start with an even digit but end with an odd one. These are also $5\times10\times10\times10\times10\times5$.

Add them all up to get the answer is $3\times(5\times10\times10\times10\times10\times5)$ which is $3\times25\times10^4$ which is $750,000$.

Comment: I don't think the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is what is being used here.

Comment: thanks, I meant the fundamental theorem of combinatorics.

Comment: Ah. I did not even know there was a fundamental theorem of combinatorics... Compared to its brothers in algebra, arithmetic and calculus, it looks pretty trivial.

Comment: Well, I remember reading it in a book, I think it was cameron's, but I can't seem to find anyone calling it that now. Oh well.

Comment: Google can still find a trace: http://www.mathreference.com/cmb,intro.html.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Count the total number of possible passwords (irregardless of starting/ending number), and then *subtract* the number of passwords that *do not* meet *either* condition: $$\text{(the total number of ALL possible passwords} = 10^6 = 1,000,000)$$ $$ {\Large \bf-} (\text{# of passwords with first digit odd AND last digit even} = 5\times 10^4\times 5 = 250,000) $$
$$= \text{ solution} = 750,000.$$

Answer (score 3):

I want to say firstly that this is basically the same information as presented in the answers by Jorge and julien, and is based off of Steve Kass' comment, but I wanted to say it in a slightly different way/different details, in case someone needs this sort of explanation.

**First**, let's see how many possible passwords there are.  Well, there are $6$ "slots," and there are $10$ possibilities for each slot.  Thus, we have $10^6 = 1000000$ possible passwords.

**Second**, let's look at how many passwords are ***not*** acceptable.  That is, they end in an even digit, *and* they start with an odd digit.  This means there are $5$ possibilities for both the starting and ending digit; the first digit can be in $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$, and the last digit can be in $\{0, 2, 4, 6, 8\}$.  The rest of the digits have $10$ possibilities.  So, the number of not acceptable passwords is:
$$5\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot5=5^2\cdot 10^4 = 250000$$

**Finally**, we know that the number of acceptable passwords is the number of total passwords minus the number of unacceptable passwords.  So, we have:

$$\text{acceptable passwords} = 1000000-250000 = 750000$$

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping to see a simpler answer, but instead I guess I'll supply one.

There's a 50% chance of the password having an even first digit.
There's a 50% chance of the password having an odd last digit.

Therefore, there's a 25% chance of the password having neither, and a 75% chance of the password having one or the other.

So, for 6 digits, the answer is 750,000.

Answer (score 1):

The passwords can start with an even  digit or  end with an odd digit. So there are three possible  cases.

1. starting with an even digit & ending with an odd digit.(represented as 2i,*,*,*,*,2j+1)
2. starting with an even digit & ending with an even digit.(represented as 2i,*,*,*,*,2j)
3. starting with an odd  digit & ending with a odd digit.(represented as 2i+1,*,*,*,*,2J+1)

for the 1st case , by the fundamental theorem , the number of possible value is 
5*10*10*10*10*5=25*250000  (as the number is coming with replacement)

for the 2nd case , the answer would be same,  5*10*10*10*10*5=25*250000.

for the 3rd case , also the answer is ,in same way , 5*10*10*10*10*5=25*250000

so, the  total answer is summing the 3 cases, 250000*3=750000.
i.e. your answer.